# Is there any way to verify Metadata?

Tags: metadata

I was just doing some thinking and I was wondering to myself - How do we know the metadata of a file is correct? What if some program modifies it? We have no actual data about the metadata itself and thus we would have no way of verifying its validity? Or do we? Are there any methods/programs we can use to validate them?

Comment: Please define "the metadata of a file" with **specific** attributes.  Metadata could be OS-level metadata (maintained by the OS) or Application metadata, maintained outside the OS, or something else entirely.  Please define your terms.

Comment: Some more details of what you're trying to accomplish would be useful. Note `debsums`, `rpm -qVa`, `mtree`, tripwire, aide, systraq, etc., verify some file metadata as part of their normal operations.

Comment: @ dthorpe and Borealid - thanks guys! I appreciate your feedback. I will accept answers as necessary from now on!

@ S. Lott and sarnold - I am more specifically talking about OS-level metadata, such as creation date, access date, file size etc.

Comment: @Drizzy: "I am more specifically talking..." Please UPDATE your question with this information.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know that metadata is valid, have something you trust sign it and attach the signature as metadata.  That way, you can know if it has been tampered with by validating the signature.

See the DKIM email-signing system.  It's designed to be decentralized and can tolerate some changes to a message's headers without invalidating the signature completely (if so desired).

Answer (score 0):

> How do we know the metadata of a file is correct? What if some program modifies it?
>
> I am more specifically talking about OS-level metadata, such as creation date, access date, file size

The question is specious.  OS-level metadata can't be "wrong".

If the access is "wrong"?  Who says what's "wrong"?  If the sysadmin changed the permissions, and you can't access it, then -- well -- you're out of luck, but the access is the access.   Who defines "wrong"?

If the size is "wrong"?  You change the size of a file by writing to it.  Either you trust the OS to handle this, or -- well -- you get another job where you can worry about things like time not working, gravity not working, and OS not keeping track of resources.

If the creation date is "wrong"?  There's no API to change this, so you have to trust the OS to maintain this.

If you're worried about super-complex virus-like software that can covertly overwrite inodes and dnodes in the OS, you have a bigger problem than "metadata".  You have a virus corrupting the OS.

Comment: Hi S.Lott,Could you get the answer of the question you tried to seek answer for ? I am in the same situation now.